Registering user doesn't fetch anymore in collection 'users'
I am building an app in Flutter, but I have an issue when I try to register and login users. Since I added Stripe, I'm receiving errors in the login and signup screen as:

flutter: Login error: type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'PigeonUserDetails?' in type cast

The problem is when I create an account the user appears in Firebase Auth, but it is not added to the 'users' collection in Firestore so it is not redirected to homepage.
Here is the code for signup:
class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final _instagramController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // Animated text centered above the widget
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
            child: Center(
              child: DefaultTextStyle(
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: AnimatedTextKit(
                  animatedTexts: [
                    TypewriterAnimatedText(
                      'Are you ready to start today?',
                      speed: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                    ),
                  ],
                  repeatForever: true,
                  pause: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                  displayFullTextOnTap: true,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // Content at the bottom
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                ),
              ),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Sign Up',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 32,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      _buildTextField('Name', controller: _nameController),
                      SizedBox(height: 16),
                      _buildTextField('Instagram Username', controller: _instagramController),
                      SizedBox(height: 16),
                      _buildTextField('Email', controller: _emailController, keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress),
                      SizedBox(height: 16),
                      _buildTextField('Password', controller: _passwordController, obscureText: true),
                      SizedBox(height: 24),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: _isLoading ? null : _signUp,
                        child: _isLoading
                            ? CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white)
                            : Text(
                                'Sign Up',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                          textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 16),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Already have an account? Log in',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTextField(String hintText, {bool obscureText = false, TextInputType? keyboardType, required TextEditingController controller}) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: hintText,
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600]),
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300]!),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      obscureText: obscureText,
      keyboardType: keyboardType,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter $hintText';
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _signUp() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });

      try {
        // 1. Create Authentication User
        final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _emailController.text.trim(),
          password: _passwordController.text,
        );

        if (userCredential.user == null) {
          throw Exception('Failed to create user');
        }

        // 2. Create User Document in Firestore
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(userCredential.user!.uid)
            .set({
          'uid': userCredential.user!.uid,
          'email': _emailController.text.trim(),
          'name': _nameController.text.trim(),
          'instagramHandle': _instagramController.text.trim(),
          'profilePicture': null,
          'subscribers': 0,
          'followers': 0,
          'following': 0,
          'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        });

        // 3. Verify document creation
        final userDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(userCredential.user!.uid)
            .get();

        if (!userDoc.exists) {
          throw Exception('Failed to create user document');
        }

        if (mounted) {
          // 4. Show success message and navigate
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(content: Text('Account created successfully!')),
          );

          // 5. Navigate to HomePage
          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
            (route) => false,
          );
        }

      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        print('Firebase Auth Error: ${e.code} - ${e.message}');
        String errorMessage;
        
        switch (e.code) {
          case 'weak-password':
            errorMessage = 'The password provided is too weak.';
            break;
          case 'email-already-in-use':
            errorMessage = 'An account already exists for that email.';
            break;
          case 'invalid-email':
            errorMessage = 'The email address is not valid.';
            break;
          default:
            errorMessage = 'An error occurred during sign up.';
        }
        
        if (mounted) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage)),
          );
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('Signup error: $e');
        if (mounted) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              content: Text('An error occurred while creating your account.'),
            ),
          );
        }
      } finally {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            _isLoading = false;
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Future<dynamic> createStripeAccount({required String email, required String name}) async {
    try {
      // Make API call to your backend to create Stripe account
      // This is just a placeholder - implement according to your backend API
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('YOUR_BACKEND_URL/create-stripe-account'),
        body: {
          'email': email,
          'name': name,
        },
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return json.decode(response.body);
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to create Stripe account');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Error creating Stripe account: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    _nameController.dispose();
    _instagramController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

and here is the code for main:
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
  // Simple Firebase initialization
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'InfluFit',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const SplashScreen(),
        '/first': (context) => FirstScreen(),
        '/signup': (context) => SignUp(),
        '/login': (context) => LoginScreen(),
        '/home': (context) => HomePage(),
      },
    );
  }
}


It appears that the error you specified is coming from LoginScreen, please include the code for it too.
